# functions and returns and formula

Tags: python

I started learning python through the book "python the hard way", I am stuck on the task #21 (http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html):

The task is given the code snippet like:

```
def add(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d + %d" % (a, b)
    return a + b

def substract(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d - %d" % (a, b)
    return a - b

def multiple(a, b):
    print "ADDING %d * %d" % (a, b)
    return a * b

def divide(a, b): 
    print "ADDING %d / %d" % (a, b)
    return a / b

print "Let's do some math with just functions!"

age = add(20, 6)
height = substract(200, 20)
weight = multiple(40, 2)
iq = divide(190, 2)

print "age: %d, height: %d, weight: %d, iq: %d" % (age, height, weight, iq)
what = add(age,multiple(iq, substract(weight, divide(height,4))))

#this is my current solution
    first_step = divide(height,4)
    two_step = substract(weight, first_step)
    three_step = multiple(iq, two_step)
    four_step = add(age, three_step)
    print four_step
#end of my current solution

print "That becomes:", what, "Can you do it by hand?"
```

to be able to obtain an output like this:

```
Let's do some math with just functions!
ADDING 30 + 5
SUBTRACTING 78 - 4
MULTIPLYING 90 * 2
DIVIDING 100 / 2
Age: 35, Height: 74, Weight: 180, IQ: 50
Here is a puzzle.
DIVIDING 50 / 2
MULTIPLYING 180 * 25
SUBTRACTING 74 - 4500
ADDING 35 + -4426
That becomes:  -4391 Can you do it by hand?
```

My question:
How would one solve it in a more *pythonic* way?

Comment: Another victim of LPTHW. I'd like to help, but I don't understand what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to view the parse tree for the equation. (Don't worry about the exact definition of parse tree.)

```
           -
          / \
         /   \
        +    1023
       / \
      /   \
     24   (/)
          / \
         /   \
        34   100
```

Using functions from the `operator` module (just to avoid defining my own), you pass the left and right children of each operator above as the arguments to the corresponding function. For example, since 34 and 100 are children of `/` in the tree above, the call is `div(34, 100)`.

Starting at the top of the tree, you see that `sub` should take two arguments, an addition and 1023. So start with a partial answer

```
answer = sub(add(??), 1023)
```

Next, the addition has arguments 24 and a division. Now your answer looks like

```
answer = sub(add(24, div(??)), 1023)
```

Finally, the division has arguments 34 and 100.

```
from operator import add, sub, div
answer = sub(add(24, div(34, 100)), 1023)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is terribly worded, but here is my interpretation:

assuming "substract" is in fact "subtract"..

```
what = add(age,multiple(iq, substract(weight, divide(height,4))))
```

implements this formula:

```
what = age + iq * (weight - height/4)
```

the formula to try: "24 + 34 / 100 - 1023"

//first I wrongly interpreted this as:

```
 24 + 34
----------
100 - 1023
```

which would have to be something like:

```
what = divide(add(24,34), substract(100, 1013))
```

so it is an exercise in understanding what is called when..
(first the parameters are called, then function using the parameters)

Edit: there is no parenteses there!

> However, because of the operators precedence, the problem is equivalent to 24 + (34 / 100) - 1023

it should have been

```
what = add(24, substract(divide(34, 100), 1023))
```

Comment: Your answer would be correct if the problem was `(24 + 34) / (100 - 1023)`. However, because of the operators precedence, the problem is equivalent to `24 + (34 / 100) - 1023`, since the division has a higher priority than addition (afaik). Your solution should then be `substract(add(24, divide(34, 100)), 1023)`.

Answer (score 0):

As functions, following the order of operations, it would look something like this. I started by putting each operation in a variable, to try to make things easier.

```
q = divide(34, 100)
s = add(24, quo)
d = subtract(sum, 1023)
```

next, I made an equation by substituting the variable names for their function names:

```
result = subtract(add(24, divide(32, 100))), 1023)
print result
```

I hope this works for you!